# Get value of data attribute using jQuery in parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

I have the following HTML code where `onclick` of `.spot-info` I want to get the value of `data-test`.

```html
    <div class="spot" id="spot-1" data-test="12345">
        <div class="spot-main">
          <span>Test</span>
          <a href="#" class="spot-info">view</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="spot" id="spot-2" data-test="67891">
        <div class="spot-main">
          <span>Test</span>
          <a href="#" class="spot-info">view</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please see my js attempt below:

```js
    $('.spot-info').click(function ( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var test = $(this).parent().parent().data('data-test');
        console.log(test);
    });
```

This test is logging `undefined` in the console. I thought this would work checking the parent of the parent of `.spot-info`.

Also, is there way chaining a lot of `parent(0)` methods together rather than using jQuery.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try **attr** instead. Also, try 'closest' instead of referring to the parent twice:

```
$('.spot-info').click(function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var test = $(this).closest('.spot').attr('data-test');
    console.log(test);
});
```

Comment: i like this, but using closest here isn't working. any idea why?

Comment: this solution is working correctly. Please accept it as answer

Comment: @HassanALi i don't know why but it is still showing undefined in my console

Comment: typo from my end. 'spot' should have been '.spot'. that should work.
https://jsfiddle.net/rvxaqxto/

Comment: @MartOosterveld ah sorry. i should have spotted it too

Comment: @HassanALi yes, but there was a typo in the answer so it wasn't working. Mart, can you please update the answer so it is correct for anyone else in the future? thanks !

Comment: It's really better to use data when you deal with `data-*` attributes...

Answer (score 3):

Better if you could use **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** or **[`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)** ,so instead of :

```
$(this).parent().parent().data('test');
```

Use :

```
$(this).closest('.spot').data('test');
$(this).parents('.spot').data('test');
```

**NOTE :** The main problem come from `.data('data-test');` When you use **[`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** function you shouldn't add the string `data-` at the start.

Hopet his helps.

---

### Working snippet

```js
$('.spot-info').click(function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var test = $(this).closest('.spot').data('test');
  
    console.log(test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spot" id="spot-1" data-test="12345">
  <div class="spot-main">
    <span>Test</span>
    <a href="#" class="spot-info">view</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="spot" id="spot-2" data-test="67891">
  <div class="spot-main">
    <span>Test</span>
    <a href="#" class="spot-info">view</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure - but I think it's this:

```
$('.spot-info').click(function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var test = $(this).parent().parent().data('test');
    console.log(test);
});
```

You don't need the `data-` prefix when fetching the data with `.data()`

Comment: this works! thanks. as an aside is there any better way of doing it rather than chaining lots of parent(0 methods together? I would fear that if the html changes this would break, bur perhaps this is the disadvantage of using jquery.

Comment: Thanks! Don't forget to mark it :-)
You may want to consider .parents(): https://api.jquery.com/parents/

Or writing your own recursive code that does the lookup.

Comment: i will accept it, but first i want to see can it be solved without using `parent().parent()` as I don't really like that

Comment: i am going to accept the `closest()` answer as i really like it. but thanks for your help also