# Get data-attribute value of parent, for element with class

Tags: jquery

I need to get the data-attribute value of an li element which is the parent of an a element with a specific class.

The html struture is

```
<ul id="fz-filteroptions"....
  <li class="nav-item" data-filter="all" role="presentation">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" role="tab" aria-selected="true">All items</a>
  </li>
```

Goals are to

- define a variable with the value of the data-filter attribute from the li.nav-item which is the parent element of a.navlink.active
- restrict search to ul#fz-filteroptions as there are other elements on the page using the same nav-item, .nav-link and .active classes

The answer linked below is close to what I need but I've been unable to adapt it.
[Get value of data attribute using jQuery in parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641343/)

Code I've tried is below.  Can anyone advise what will achieve the goal please?

```
var filterActive = $('#fz-filteroptions').find('a.nav-link.active');
console.log('>> filterActive: ' + filterActive);
// retuns object

var filterValue = filterActive.parent().attr('data-test');
console.log('>> filterValue: ' + filterValue);
// returns undefined

var filterValue2 = $(filterActive).parent().attr('data-test');
console.log('>> filterValue2: ' + filterValue);
// returns undefined

// direct access
console.log( $('#fz-filteroptions').find('a.nav-link.active').parent().attr('data-test') );
// returns undefined
```

Comment: `data-test` doesn't exist in your html.. but `data-filter` does.. and indeed: `$('ul li > a.nav-link.active').parent('li').data('filter')` this works

Comment: Thanks Diego, your prompt pointed me at the solution.

I don't see a way to assign this as the answer so you get the points but here's a working fiddle of the working code - check the console to see the output.

https://jsfiddle.net/krhj4365/

Comment: don't worry. Just add an upvote on my comment for the sake of it and the question will be considered closed at some point I guess. It was an easy fix